# Problem using cloned array data without modifying original (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, loops, increment

I have a project to do for a Python initiation course, but I am stuck close to the end because of a problem.

My problem is the following one :
I want to use a double of my "tdata" data frame composed of the values of the different attributes of a class called "world" to make changes to it. (Trying to do some forecast with the current levels of the indicators)
I tried to do it by generating a new data frame "graphdat" which I used in a function to generate a graph.

My problem is that, in the end, my "tdata" array is also modified.

I tried to use graphdat = tdata.copy() , but it returns an AttributeError : 'world' object has no attribute 'copy'.

Anyone would know how I could do it in another way?

Thank you!

```
def graph_ppm(self):
        self.price_ppm = 10
        self.budget -= self.price_ppm
        period = tdata.period
        
        graphdat = tdata

        while period < 30:
            period +=1
            graphdat.sup = (graphdat.emit - graphdat.absorb)
            graphdat.ppm += graphdat.sup


            yppm.append(round(graphdat.ppm,2))
```

**EDIT:**

I think I misunderstood the whole problem.
As suggested by *Md Imbesat Hassan Rizvi*, I decided to use graphdat = copy.deepcopy(tdata) but I want to use this function a multiple-time, I do want to reinitialize graphdat to the current level of the parameters and the current period.
The problem is that I obtain this kind of graph if a run this function multiple times :

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJTmV.png)

My maximum period is 30, and I want to get rid of the past values creating a very new graph.

```
def graph_temp(self):

    self.price_temp = 10
    self.budget -= self.price_temp
    
    graphdat = copy.deepcopy(tdata)
    period = graphdat.period
    plx.clear_plot()

    while period < 30:
        period +=1
        graphdat.sup = (graphdat.emit - graphdat.absorb)
        graphdat.ppm += graphdat.sup

        if graphdat.ppm <380: 
            graphdat.temperature += graphdat.sup * 0.001
        if graphdat.ppm <400: 
            graphdat.temperature += (graphdat.sup) * 0.001
        if graphdat.ppm <450:
            graphdat.temperature += (graphdat.sup) * 0.005
            graphdat.pop_satisfaction -=1
        else:
            graphdat.temperature += (graphdat.sup) * 0.01


        ytemp.append(round(graphdat.temperature,2)) 

    limittemp = [2]*31
    recomtemp = [1.5]*31

    plx.plot(ytemp, label="Temperatures forecast",line_marker = "•")
    plx.plot(limittemp, label="Catastrophe level",line_marker = "-")
    plx.plot(recomtemp, label="Limit level after period 30",line_marker = "=")
    plx.xlabel('Temperatures')
    plx.ylabel('Period')
    plx.title('Title')
    plx.figsize(50, 25)
    plx.ticks(31, 11)

    return plx.show()
```

Comment: Since you have a user-defined class, you need define a method to clone the instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `tdata` appears to be an instance of a custom class `world` for which copy attribute doesn't exist, you can make a copy of it using methods from copy module:

```
import copy
graphdat = copy.deepcopy(tdata)
```

Henceforth, `graphdat` and `tdata` will be different instances of the `world` class.